# Group by only particular values of a column

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following table for example

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| ID |  TYPE |     NAME     |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 13    | Free color   |
| 2  | 15    | Free food    |
| 3  | 15    | Free burger  |
| 4  | 17    | Free cloths  |
| 5  | 13    | Free crayons |
| 6  | 12    | Free wood    |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

I am trying to build a query which would `group by` only type 15, if I use the normal `group by`, on the column `type`, it would group by all the types, even type 13, which I don't want.  I only want to group by the column type on specific values(here 15). Is it possible in MySQL? If so, how?

The expected result would look something like this:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| ID |  TYPE |     NAME     |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 13    | Free color   |
| 2  | 15    | Free food    |
| 4  | 17    | Free cloths  |
| 5  | 13    | Free crayons |
| 6  | 12    | Free wood    |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Can you please share the result you're trying to get for this sample data? It would help us understand the question.

Comment: If we do a count with the normal group by, we will get 4. But, here, i want, 5 because I want to group by only type 15

Comment: Please edit your question

Comment: Which `id` and which `name` do you want for `15`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
GROUP BY IF(`Type` = 15, 0 , id);
```

Comment: This returns an indeterminate result. So probably not very useful.

Comment: This works for me. @Strawberry Can you elaborate why it wont be useful please?

Comment: You want food, but this could just as arbitrarily return burgers - as in fact it would (albeit still arbitrarily) if you happened to place an index on name.

Answer (score -1):

Why not two queries?

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE Type = 15
GROUP BY Type

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE Type <> 15
```